# X-Frame-Options поведение не соответствует ожидаемому

Tags: java, servlet

У меня есть backend(localhost:8080) на tomcat+java+servlets. Front на js(localhost:8081).

Я вставляю содержимое с бэкенда(jsf странички) в iframe.
1) на бекенде добавляю фильр для хедеров

`response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW FROM http://localhost:8080");`
 все работает хорошо, но это гап в безопасности.
Если этот хедер не добавить - будет ошибка кросс - доменного запроса.

2) Если уточняю для каких url разрешить X-Frame-Options,

```
response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW FROM http://localhost:8081"); 
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

то получаю ошибку и сообщение в консоли браузера:

> Refused to display
>   'http://localhost:8081/app/jsf/payments.jsf?hide=true' in a frame
>   because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting
>   values ('DENY, ALLOW FROM http://localhost:8081'). Falling back to
>   'deny'.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно заменить headers на response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors http://localhost:8081");

Потому что X-Frame-Options -устаревший вариант, не поддерживается Google Chrome.